# dynamodb's npm module > (greater than) query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to understand how to perform `> operator` query

```
var db = require('dynamodb').ddb({
  accessKeyId: '1',
  secretAccessKey: '1',
  endpoint: 'dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
});
db.query('mydb', 'examplekey', {
  limit: 30
}, function(err, res, cap) {
  console.log(res.items);
});
```

the sorting key is "time" and it's defined on dynamodb schema:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "rangeKeyCondition" option to your query that looks something like:

```
db.query('mydb', 'examplekey', {
  limit: 30,
  rangeKeyCondition: {GT: 5}
}, function(err, res, cap) {
  console.log(res.items);
});
```

The "rangeKeyCondition" is an object defining the comparison. The key specifies the comparison type (in your case use "GT" for "greater than"). The value is the value used to compare against your range (sort) keys.

Comment: thank you, for someone else struggling the same question "EQ" would be "equal to"